# Neo4j-jdbc hashmap or json in prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

another question aboit neo4j-jdbc driver. According to Rest api doc there is a way to create a node by passing a map:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put( "name", "Andres" );
props.put( "position", "Developer" );

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "props", props );
String query = "CREATE ({props})";
engine.execute( query, params );
```

I have to create a node with a lot of properties, and i get a json for that. is there a way to create a node like so

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(json);
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Map.class);
...
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE (n{1}");
preparedStatement.setObject(1, map);
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Thanx all!

Comment: Seems to be a problem. The question at neo4j's google group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/2kEfVieckUI

Answer (score 0):

Node with multiple Properties:-

```
 Map<String, Object> courseNodeInfo=new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    courseNodeInfo.put("name",courseId);
                    courseNodeInfo.put("createtime",createTime);
                    courseNodeInfo.put("title",title);
                    courseNodeInfo.put("status", "draft");
                    courseNodeInfo.put("coursetype", courseType);
                    courseNodeInfo.put("sectionexist",isSectionExist);
                    courseNodeInfo.put("coverimage", "coursecover.jpg");

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Connection connect = null;
            int status = 00;
            try {
                connect = graphdbConnect();

                //String insert = "CREATE (n:Test {1})";
                String query = "CREATE (n:" + nodeLabel +"{1}) RETURN n";
                query=query.toLowerCase();

                try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query)){

                    preparedStatement.setObject(1,courseNodeInfo);
                    System.out.println(query+" ---> query");
                    preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    status = ServerStatusReport.OK();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```